# Loop Copy Cell Name As New Workbook

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I am trying to read a column of cells and when it finds a cell with info in it create a new work book and use that cell as the name. I am trying to save it to a folder on my desktop named Book1. I am a little stuck and not sure where to go next any ideas???

```
Sub blair()
Dim Aname As String

For ptr = 2 To 300
    If Cells(ptr, "b") = vbNullString Then
        Cells(ptr, "b") = Cells(ptr, "a").Offset(-1, 0)

    ElseIf Cells(ptr, "b") > 0 Then
       Aname = ActiveCell.Value
       Workbooks.Add
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Aname & ".xls"
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A further example of what you data looks like, and what you need to do would be useful. Do you only have numeric vaues, what if you have duplicates, do you have data in column a to replace emty cells in column B, should the new workbooks be blank or copies of the one with the existing code etc.

Comment: So do you want blank workbooks called "6010.1.xlsx" etc?

Comment: I have listed the cell location and then what that set of data would look like. I am wanting a program to read down column A. When it finds a cell that contains info use that as a new work book name and save on my desktop. There will be no duplicates of cell data each entry will be unique
A1: 6010.1
A2: Null
A3: 6010.2
A4: Null
A5: Null
A6: 6020.1
A7: Null
A8: 6020.5
A9: Null
A10: Null
A11: Null
A12: 9010.1
A13: Null
A14: Null
A15: Null
A16: Null
A17: 9020.1
A18: Null
A19: Null
A20: Null
A21: Null
A22: 9030.1

Comment: yes just a blank work book is all i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is below.

- checks that the *Book1* folder exists on the user Desktop  (works regardless of OS path)
- the code creates a single sheet blank workbook, then saves it in this directory as the template for the new files to be created
- for efficiency `FileCopy` is used to make the new versions, rather than  creating, saving and closing a new workook repeatedly
- null values are skipped
- the code uses a variant array for quick processing of the values

Some further minor tweaks may be needed if your data format varied. For example, testing for characters that cannot be used in file names.

**code**

```
Sub NB()
    Dim X
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim strDT As String
    Dim strNewBook As String
    Dim objWS As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim bNewBook As Boolean

    Set objWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strDT = objWS.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Book1"
    If Len(Dir(strDT, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No such directory", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        If Len(X(lngCnt, 1)) > 0 Then
            If Not bNewBook Then
                'make a single sheet workbook for first value
                Set WB = Workbooks.Add(1)
                WB.SaveAs strDT & "\" & X(lngCnt, 1) & ".xls"
                strNewBook = WB.FullName
                WB.Close
                bNewBook = True
            Else
                FileCopy strNewBook, strDT & "\" & X(lngCnt, 1) & ".xls"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I keep on getting "No such directory" when i try and run the program

Comment: You do have a directory called *Book1* on your Desktop?

Comment: Yeah I did not add the 1 at the end of book and that fixed it. I showed my coworker this and he asked if more features that could be added? I have provided a link of they data format that is in the excel https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ar-_qRO59GUfdDJvZEVpSGEzXzRFTEJvUTFoc241TkE#gid=0. I need to keep the current code but add on more info to the out put the final excel documents. I need to populate tabs and within those tabs copy existing information over see link for explanation. Thanks so much again for the help and if this is possible it would be HUGE time saver at work. Thanks